# How to add animation to a text view in android

Tags: android, animation, fadein

I have a `TextView` and I'm trying to add a fade in animation to it. My code is returning `null` and I don't understand why.

Here is my implementation

This is the `fade_in.xml`

```
    <alpha
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    android:fillAfter="true"
            android:duration="1000"
            android:fromAlpha="0.0"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
            android:toAlpha="1.0"/>
```

and here is how im using it in the corresponding activity

```
    tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
//-- the below line is returning null
            animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fade_in);

            animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    Intent it  = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(it);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            tv.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Please provide the error log.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Android TextView Annimation example

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
      android:fromXScale="1.0"
      android:fromYScale="1.0"
      android:toXScale="2.0"
      android:toYScale="2.0"
      android:duration="3000" />
</set>
```

Code

```
private void RunAnimation() 
{
  Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);
  a.reset();
  TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstTextView);
  tv.clearAnimation();
  tv.startAnimation(a);
}
```

For More :

http://chiuki.github.io/advanced-android-textview/#/5

http://www.hascode.com/2010/09/playing-around-with-the-android-animation-framework/

Comment: I would recommend also using an interpolator, because else the animation will just jump from size 1 to 2 after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

You can load animations from AnimationUtils class in Android and set it to a textview in android.

```
textview.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_in));
```

and you can stop animation using,

```
textview.clearAnimation();
```

Comment: can i set the animation speed of this Textview? Like i am using animation in my splash screen and my text is animated but its animating very fast.

Answer (score 2):

Is your textview id correct?? First check if you are getting your textview id correctly in your app

Comment: Based on comment in other answer - no, it is not correct: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)' on a null" this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You need **setAnimation** in your TextView

Example:

```
tv.setAnimation( animation );
```

Comment: i have tried that also..but still it is saying the same thing

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)' on a null

Answer (score 0):

Use Animator/AnimatorSet Animation is legacy code