# I wanna display a TextView after say couple of seconds. No idea how to do it

Tags: android-activity

new to android and I don't know how to display a View after some time. I don't want codes, just want some guidance or resources so I can learn. Already googled it in vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use handler to post in UI thread . Then set time using postDelayed method of Handler class .

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Set the text in your textview here
  }
}, TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: @ArpitChhabra I have posted sample snippet .

Comment: Actually it says can't resolve symbol 'handler' and postDelayed method

Comment: I copied the above code and pasted it in onCreate method

Comment: @Arpit Chhabra Handler is a class . You need to import it

Comment: In place of TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS put the time in milliseconds after which you want to display textView

Comment: got it and imported it Thanks!

Comment: Is it Working ?

Comment: You never asked for animation

Comment: now I'm asking how to put some animation or transition in android?
and thanks for your help so far

Comment: I think I answered your question.  Anyway to know how to animate visit this link .http://stackoverflow.com/a/34089296/5879376