# Why does my app crash while using animation of alpha on an Text View

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

My app is crashing while using alpha animation on a TextView
Animation Code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:duration="800">
    </alpha>

</set>
```

My animation Load code
Is it a problem if i have called the animation an a method not in onCreate?

```
alpha= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( this,R.anim.alpha );
minusLife.setAnimation( alpha )
```

;

This is what Run section Says

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)' on a null object reference
    at com.stib.free.GameActivity.collisionControl(GameActivity.java:504)
    at com.stib.free.GameActivity$2$1.run(GameActivity.java:113)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
```

Can u tell what went wrong

Comment: is the XML file named `alpha.xml` and located in `res/anim/`? The filename will be used as the resource ID.

Comment: Possibly, you haven't initialized the TextView properly

Comment: check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34089296/12709358

Answer (score 0):

your textview is null and you forget to initialize it.

```
minusLife = findViewById(your textview xml id);
alpha= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( this,R.anim.alpha );
minusLife.setAnimation( alpha );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am able to change text and all.

Comment: hey,any answer yet?

Comment: are you sure textview isn't null? before run animation check textview nullability